# Ubuntu server in azure cloud: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting while restart apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, sudo

I am creating a ubunu virtual machine in my azure cloud service and installed the lampp stack and phpmyadmin.

Instllation is completed without any problem and for accessing the phpmyadmin i have added the following line in `etc\apahe2\apache.conf` file

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

But when i restart the apache after saving the file using the command `sudo service restart apache2` i will get the following error.

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Please help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`sudoers` file should be owned by `root:root`.

```
chown root:root sudoers
```

as root.

Comment: Can't get your answer